# Is there a way to fix jupyter notebook css to allow page breaks?

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I want to generate a pdf from a custom-formatted jupyter notebook. I have managed to do that with in two steps:

1. `jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb`
2. Using [chrome to-pdf-print](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf) `chrome --headless --to-pdf-print=mynotebook.pdf mynotebook.html`

I prefer to stick to the HTML/CSS stack - rather than LaTeX - as this gives the best results for graphs.

Now, the one thing that I can't get to work is to add page breaks using CSS `page-break-before`. [This issue in the nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/607) project mentions that this switch is overriden somewhere in the CSS hierarchy, but a I can't figure out where.

What I would like is to use `custom.css` that contains something like this:

```
@media print {
h1, h2 {
    page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```

Testing with a simple html document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World (heading 1)</h1>
    <p>This is a web page.</p>
    <h1>Another heading 1</h1>
    <p>Some random text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

gives me exactly what I want: a page break when printing with chrome.

But using `custom.css` with the static html output from `nbconvert` doesn't give page breaks. I have tried commenting out all instances of `page-break-inside: avoid` in the html, but still no luck.

I assume this must be fix-able within CSS, but I don't know how. Suggestions, anyone? Willing to pay for a solution, since I need it for a client. Note this is similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884142/best-way-to-print-jupyter-notebook-slides-how-to-put-a-page-break), but thought it's best to start a new thread.

Environment:
- OSX 10.14.5
- Python 3.7
- IPython 7.2.0
- nbconvert 5.4.1
- Chrome 76

Comment: Looking at how CSS works, it may be I need to alter the properties of the jupyter notebook CSS class, rather than `h1`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance